# Пожалуйста, помогите распарсить JSON

Tags: java, json, vkontakte-api, парсер

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "first_name": "Вася",
      "last_name": "Пупкин"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Что вы используете: GSON или org.json ?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Спасибо большое за ответ а можете подсказать точное название библиотеки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью `org.json` ([ссылка](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211)):

```
String responseString = "{\"response\":[{\"id\":0,\"first_name\":\"Вася\",\"last_name\":\"Пупкин\"}]}";
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseString);
JSONArray responseArray = response.getJSONArray("response");
JSONObject user = responseArray.getJSONObject(0);

String first_name = user.getString("first_name");

String last_name = user.getString("last_name");
```

С помощью `Google GSON` ([ссылка](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1)):

```
String responseString = "{\"response\":[{\"id\":0,\"first_name\":\"Вася\",\"last_name\":\"Пупкин\"}]}";

JsonElement responseElement = new JsonParser().parse(responseString);
JsonObject response = responseElement.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray responseArray = response.getAsJsonArray("response");
JsonObject user = responseArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();

String first_name = user.get("first_name").toString();
String last_name = user.get("last_name").toString();
```

Всё парсится довольно легко, по аналогии. Есть и другие возможные способы парсинга, для начала вам, я думаю, будет достаточно и этих двух.