# Не получается распарсить JSON

Tags: java, json

Есть вот такой JSON:

```
{
"sourceId": "currency-cash",
"date": "2017-09-07T15:56:32+03:00",
"organizations": [{
 {
"orgType": 1,
"address": "ул. Автозаводская, 54\/19",
"regionId": "0,7oiylpmiow8iy1smadi",
"phone": "123",
"link": "http:\/\/organizations\/ru\/info\/currency\/-\/7oiylpmiow8iy1smb0b\/cash",
"id": "7oiylpmiow8iy1smb0b",
"cityId": "7oiylpmiow8iy1smadi",
"oldId": 1266,
"title": "Bank",
"branch": false,
"currencies": {
    "EUR": {
        "ask": "31.6500",
        "bid": "30.9000"
    },
    "USD": {
        "ask": "26.4500",
        "bid": "26.0500"
    }
}
}
```

А точнее это часть из файла. Как получить доступ, перебрать и вывести "currencies"? На данный момент вывожу всё, но как добраться до "currencies" не пойму.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();  
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("cur.json"));

String objName = (String) jsonObject.get("sourceId");
             System.out.println("Title: "+objName);

             JSONArray org= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("organizations");
            // for(int i=0; i<org.size(); i++){System.out.println("The " + i + " element of the array: "+org.get(i));}

             Iterator i = org.iterator();
             while (i.hasNext())
             {
       JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) i.next();
       System.out.println("Банк: "+ innerObj.get("title") + " Адрес: " + innerObj.get("address"));

     }
```

Используется json-simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если всё-таки интересует решение для simple-json, то можно вспомнить, что `JSONObject` является наследником `HashMap`, соответственно можно воспользоваться методом [`HashMap::entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet--):

```
JSONObject currencies = (JSONObject) innerObj.get("currencies")
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : currencies.entrySet()) {
    String currency = entry.getKey();
    JSONObject currencyInfo = (JSONObject) entry.getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Но вообще лучше использовать не simple-json, а что-нибудь другое, например [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: Всем спасибо. А к gson пригляжусь. Возможно её и проще\удобнее использовать.

Comment: Обязательно приглядись, она очень классная. Можешь задавать вопросы по ней :)

Comment: Задал бы, но в профиле у вас нету возможности отправлять сообщения.

Comment: Я имел в виду задавать вопросы на ruSO :) Если хочешь, можешь в [ВК](https://vk.com/write104171944) спросить, например.

Answer (score 5):

Вы зачем-то усложняете:

```
String sourceString = ""; // весь json считываем в строку
JSONObject full = new JSONObject(sourceString);

String sourceId = full.getString("sourceId");
JSONArray organizations = full.getJSONArray("organizations");
```

И далее по аналогии.
Я привел пример использования библиотеки [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20170516).

В другом ответе ([Пожалуйста, помогите распарсить JSON](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698167/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json/698170#698170)) я также показывал, как можно парсить json и другими библиотеками.

По поводу конкретно вашего json - в этом моменте:

```
"organizations": [{
 {
```

Не совсем понятно, что содержится. Элементы либо содержатся в jsonarray под индексами:

```
{"response":["item1",1,false]}
```

Либо в jsonobject под ключами:

```
{"response":{"key":"value"}}
```

У вас же jsonobject, видимо, каким-то образом находится прямо внутри jsonobject: `[{{` в примере строчки, что я привел чуть выше. Видимо, вы что-то не так скопировали.

Comment: Но ведь он использует библиотеку json-simple...

Comment: @diraria я привел пример библиотеки, с которой можно распарсить json гораздо проще. Разве это плохо? К тому же, приведенный пример json'а какой-то неправильный.

Comment: Нет, это отлично, не знаю, почему он пользуется такой неудобной библиотекой. // а почему приведённый пример json'а неправильный?

Comment: @diraria дополнил ответ.